# Not getting Artist name from SoundCloud API

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, get, soundcloud

I am using Sound Cloud API to get the records based on song which I am showing the records in my iOS Application.But the problem is I am not getting artist name but if I used iTunes API I am getting the Artist Name.

This is an API which I am using for Sound Cloud:

**"http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=Beautiful&client_id=Client_ID"**